# How to extract link http in capture with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, http, web, beautifulsoup

How to find only the "http: //" links as a BeautifulSoup method in python. My results are always `<href>` and `<a>`. Want to capture links to test http requests.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://tre-ap.jus.br")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)

for rec in soup.find_all('a'):
    if 'href' in rec.attrs:
        print(rec['href'])
```

Comment: `print(rec.attrs['href'])`, you can also skip the `if` statement

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I was testing pass by step, I'm starting with python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you could use python regex.
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html
Then you would just search over all your text files for the pattern you want

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://tre-ap.jus.br")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)

for rec in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("(^http://)")}):
    print(rec['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid regex:

```
for rec in soup.find_all('a'):
    if rec.attrs['href'].startswith('http://'):
        print(rec.attrs['href'])
```